# Using jQuery to copy value from image source's file name to process and paste into html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, automation, css-selectors

Hi i'm trying to use jQuery/javascript to make my life easier. I'm trying to use it to auto fill in the various html elements with the name of the place and country which comes from the file name of the image. Below is a sample of some of the html i have to work with:

```
<div class="boxgrid">
<a href="gallery/angkor - cambodia.jpg" title="[PLACE] - [COUNTRY]">
  <img src="gallery/thumbs/angkor - cambodia.jpg" alt="[PLACE] - [COUNTRY]" width="100" height="100"/>
</a>
  <div class="boxcaption">
    <span class="place">[PLACE]</span>
    <span class="country">[COUNTRY]</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Imagine this block of html is repeated multiple times for every image in the gallery so i assume .each() will need to be used.

The idea is that [NAME OF PLACE] and [NAME OF COUNTRY] should be filled in with the image's file name using the - (dash) as the delimiter between the two values. How can I accomplish this with jQuery/javascript? (i realise i should use a server side language or go about this another way but this is what i'm restricted to)

As a bonus the first letter of each of the values should be capitalised, for example Angkor - Cambodia .

Thank you, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: A goodly portion of user-agents for whom alt text would be useful, won't support JavaScript. You should really do this server side. Also - don't duplicate captions as alt text, its useless. The alternative should communicate whatever the image communicates - and is redundent if the text below it communicates the same information. Likewise, providing the information in a link as well, is also useless. http://www.alanflavell.org.uk/alt/alt-text.html is worth a read.

Comment: To partly respond to your comment i did state that i knew the technique was flawed. The reasoning behind wanting to have a title attribute was because i wanted to implement a jQuery lightbox plugin (http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) and the caption it generates comes from the title attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the full code with trimming and capitalization of the first letter for Place and Country.

```
String.prototype.capitalize = function(){
    return this.replace(/\S+/g, function(a){
        return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    });
};

$(function(){
 $('.boxgrid').each(function(){
    var placeCountry = $(this).find('img').attr('src')
                            .replace('gallery/thumbs/','')
                            .replace('.jpg','').capitalize();

    var place = $.trim(placeCountry.split('-')[0]); 
    var country = $.trim(placeCountry.split('-')[1]);
    $(this).find('a').attr('title',placeCountry);
    $(this).find('img').attr('alt',placeCountry);
    $(this).find('.place').html(place);
    $(this).find('.country').html(country);
 });
});
```

Comment: I would like to thank you very much for your time and effort in solving this problem, I will try the code now. 

I would like to add that although this may seem a very specific problem i think it may help others to understand how to use existing information on the page and repurpose it for other uses.

Comment: i get an error: $(this).find("img").attr("src").replace("gallery/thumbs/", "").replace(".jpg", "").capitalize is not a function

Comment: The error seems to be solved by putting the capitalize function before the rest of the code. Thanks.

Comment: 1 thing i've added is trim to get rid of the whitespace from the place and country variables.

    var place = $.trim(placeCountry.split('-')[0]);
    var country = $.trim(placeCountry.split('-')[1]);